# Timestamp script for multiple columns (Specific ones) for multiple tabs in one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am trying to find a script that add a timestamp whenever any changes happen in specific columns. For example any changes happen in column G "Status" and column J "No. of follow up calls" will be reflected in Column N & O "Time Stamp for new Prospects"   "Time Stamp for follow up calls".
To watch col= 7, 10
To timestamp= 14,15
And all of these will be made in certain tabs in the same google sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

You are looking for an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger.

- The following code checks if the edited sheet belongs to `onEditSheets` using the [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method. Please **change** part of the code to include the sheets/tabs you want this function to interact with:

  ```
  const onEditSheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet5'];
  ```

Then it adds a timestamp whenever there is a change in the respective
columns you mentioned in your question.

```
function onEdit(e) {

   const row = e.range.getRow();
   const col = e.range.getColumn();     
   const onEditSheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet5'];
   const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   const columns = as.getRange(1,1,1,as.getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat();
   const columns_n = ['Status','No. of follow up calls','Time Stamp for new Prospects','Time Stamp for follow up calls'];
   const columns_i = columns_n.map(c=>columns.indexOf(c)+1);

   if(onEditSheets.includes(as.getName()) && col == columns_i[0] && row > 1) 
   {  
   as.getRange(row,columns_i[2]).setValue(new Date());
   }

   if(onEditSheets.includes(as.getName()) && col == columns_i[1] && row > 1) 
   {  
   as.getRange(row,columns_i[3]).setValue(new Date());
   }

}
```

---

### Instructions:

1. Click on **Tools** => **Script editor**:

   [image: explanation]
2. **Copy** and **Paste** the aforementioned code snippet to an empty .gs file
   in the script editor and click **save**:

   [image: example2]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly, you saved my day!!!

Comment: Is there a way instead of adding the column number, just add the column header instead? The problem I am facing right now is that some sheets are not in the same order.